# Who are these characters in episode 25 of Sword Art Online?

Tags: sword-art-online

In [13:32](http://www.crunchyroll.com/sword-art-online/episode-25-the-world-seed-606787)

[image]

Who are the characters in the 3rd and 6th position from the left side? I can't recognize what episodes they were from previously.

Comment: I won't be surprise if they were just their classmate or something like that

Comment: @ShinobuOshino if they were, it would make more sense that they would be also wearing the same uniform, but... I think this is done intentionally to distinguish that the others come from a different place.

Comment: @Krazer after the SAO players woke up, those who was still in school at the time were put together in the same special schools/classes to help them rehabilitate from the missing year(s).

Comment: it's possible the ones not in uniform did go to the same school but were the first to wake up so their studies finished and the one in uniform were filtered to and trapped in ALO after SAO was cleared so the ones not in unifrom may have finished just around the time Asuna woke up and just briefly met her, this ofcause assumes Silica and Lisbeth were also trapped ones.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the left to the right (not including Silica, Asuna, and Lisbeth):

- [Yolko](http://swordartonline.wikia.com/wiki/Yolko) (Ep. 5)
- [Sasha](http://swordartonline.wikia.com/wiki/Sasha) (Ep. 11), the one with the glasses
- [Yulier](http://swordartonline.wikia.com/wiki/Yulier) (Ep. 12)

Comment: Which one is Yolko? First from the left or third from the left? I think this answer would be better if you include a complete list of the people from left to right. I only notice Silica and Asuna in that picture.

Comment: All of the characters are as follows (from the left): Lisbeth, Silica, Yolko, Asuna, Sasha, Yulier.